# Python TCP sockets: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I wrote a python script that performs file transfer over TCP connection.
Every third or fourth time I start the program (sometimes more often), an error occurs, with message: "[Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host". Error occurs on server-side, a few seconds after the client send all data and closes. Why client close connection before the server received all the bytes? Isn't the TCP protocol reliable? Client should wait to receive ACK's for every segment. When I capture packets with Wireshark, I get a bunch of messages: 'Tcp Spurious Retransmission', 'TCP ACKed unseen segment', and at the end, RST flag is sent by client. The problem does not occur when server listens on localhost:12000. I know that I can use HTTP for this purpose, but I want to try to code it by myself.

This is my code:

```
#Server.py    
from message import message
from socket import *

interface = '...'
port = 12000

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind((interface, port))
serverSocket.listen(1)

connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()

msg = message(connectionSocket)
msg.recv()

print 'Header:'
for key, value in msg.getHeader().iteritems():
    print '\t' + key + ': ' + value

f = open('out.pdf', 'wb')
f.write(msg.getData())
f.close()

connectionSocket.shutdown(SHUT_WR)
connectionSocket.close()

serverSocket.close()
```

---

```
#Client.py
from message import message
from socket import *

host = '...'
port = 12000

f = open('in.pdf', 'rb')
data = f.read()
f.close()

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((host, port))

msg = message(clientSocket)
msg.send(data)
clientSocket.shutdown(SHUT_WR)
clientSocket.close()
```

---

```
#message.py
import socket

### This class encapsulates a protocol message exchanged by two end-users on the Internet.

#Structure of message:
    #header
        #field: value
        #...
        #field: value
    #
    #data
    #   ...
    #   ...

#Supported fields:
    #size - size of data in bytes (required)

class message:
    CHUNK_SIZE = 65536 #64KB

    def __init__(self, sock, dataSeparator = '\n\n', fieldSeparator = '\n', fieldValueSeparator = ':'):
        self.__sock = sock
        self.__dataSeparator = dataSeparator
        self.__fieldSeparator = fieldSeparator
        self.__fieldValueSeparator = fieldValueSeparator

    #public methods
    def recv(self):
        #init data
        self.__data = ''
        self.__header = dict()
        self.__junkData = ''

        self.__getHeader()

        dataSize = int(self.__header['size'])

        self.__getData(dataSize)

    def send(self, msg, header = dict()):
        #init data
        self.__data = ''
        self.__header = header
        self.__header['size'] = str(len(msg))

        #join header and message
        i = 0
        headerLen = len(self.__header)
        for key, value in self.__header.iteritems():
            i = i + 1
            self.__data += key + self.__fieldValueSeparator + value
            if i < headerLen:
                self.__data += self.__fieldSeparator
        self.__data += self.__dataSeparator + msg

        total_sent = 0
        size = len(self.__data)
        while total_sent < size:
            sent = self.__sock.send(self.__data[total_sent:total_sent + message.CHUNK_SIZE])
            total_sent += sent
            if sent == 0:
                raise IOError('Connection problem.')

    def getHeader(self):
        return self.__header

    def getData(self):
        return self.__data

    def getJunkData(self):
        return self.__junkData

    #private methods
    def __getHeader(self):
        tmp = ''

        while True:
            chunk = self.__sock.recv(message.CHUNK_SIZE)

            if not chunk:
                raise IOError('Connection problem.')

            tmp += chunk
            if self.__dataSeparator in tmp:
                pos = tmp.find(self.__dataSeparator)
                headerData = tmp[:pos]

                #parse header data
                for line in headerData.split(self.__fieldSeparator):
                    parts = line.split(self.__fieldValueSeparator)
                    if len(parts) != 2:
                        raise AttributeError('Incorrect attribute format.')
                    self.__header[parts[0].strip()] = parts[1].strip()

                if 'size' not in self.__header: #size field is required
                    raise AttributeError('Field \'size\' is required.')

                size = int(self.__header['size'])
                self.__data = tmp[pos + 2:pos + 2 + size]
                self.__junkData = tmp[pos + 2 + size:]

                break

    def __getData(self, size):
        total = len(self.__data)
        diff = size - total
        chunk = ''

        while total < size:
            chunk = self.__sock.recv(message.CHUNK_SIZE)

            if not chunk:
                raise IOError('Connection problem.')

            diff = size - total
            self.__data += chunk[:diff]
            total += min(diff, len(chunk))
            print 'chunk len: ' + str(len(chunk)) + ', diff: ' + str(diff) + ', total: ' + str(total) + ', size: ' + str(size)
            #print str(total) + '/' + str(size)

        self.__junkData += chunk[diff:]
```